# Connection django-select2 with django-filters

Tags: python, django, jquery-selectors, jquery-select2, django-filter

I want to connect with select2 django with django-filters. I want to have a nice selector to select users.
I do not know where to put the following code in the code django-filters.

```
from django_select2 import *

class UserChoices(AutoModelSelect2Field):
    queryset = User.objects
    search_fields = ['word__icontains', ]
```

Comment: Have you gotten any further with this? I noticed there's a very tiny bit about customizing widgets in the django-filter docs: http://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#overriding-filterset-methods

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it, sticking to the [django-filter example](http://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html) and using [django-select2](http://django-select2.readthedocs.org/):

```
import django_filters
from django_select2.widgets import Select2Widget
from .models import Product

class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    name = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(
        queryset=Product.objects.all(),
        widget=Select2Widget
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name', 'price', ]
```

Make sure you have jquery in your (base) template. Then this is what you'll get:

[image]